# Is that possible to install SQL Server on a Synology nas?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, synology

I developed an ASP.NET MVC web application using SQL Server and my company owner ask me to publish on Synology disk station ds216+ii.

I found that I can host .net core app on Synology, but not ASP.NET MVC, and also found that SQL Server is also not possible to install.

My question is that can I upload a simple asp.net mvc web app, install SQL Server on Synology?

Comment: It *might* be possible - with ASP.NET MVC Core, and SQL Server for Linux - but given the *very limited* RAM resources those NAS systems typically have, even if you *can* install it, it won't be a very nice and well performing setup - just **don't do it** - not worth the trouble IMHO

Answer (score 5):

I am looking into it right now and you can use docker to get a container from Microsoft.
https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/mssql-server-linux/
If you have an 8GB RAM setup in the NAS it can definitely run on in terms of system resources.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

With the way .NET is now these days, yes it *should* be possible. Though, you will be limited to only .NET Core and SqlServer for Linux, since you will need a cross-platform solution because Synology OS is Linux based.

- Look into .NET Core for your Web App: https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#macos
- The new version of SQL Server supports linux: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-setup

**Edit**:

You can also look into Docker, and have a container for both your web app and also SQL Server.

See: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1166251/Run-Net-Core-apps-in-Docker-on-Synology